# Write a function that calculate the sum of integers in a list in Erlang

Tags: erlang

As I'm learning Erlang just by reading books and doing my own exercises (NOT for homework), I'm struggling with even the most simple task that I mentioned in the title.

Here's what I've done:

I created a file called sum.erl with the following lines of code:

```
-module(mysum).
-export([mysum/1]).

mysum(L) -> 
   mysum(L, 0).

mysum([H|T], acc) -> 
   mysum(T, H + acc); 

mysum([], acc) ->
   acc.
```

Then I compile:

```
erl sum.erl
```

which takes me to a shell.  There, I typed:

```
1> L = [1, 3, 7].
[1, 3, 7]
2> mysum(L).
** exception error: undefined shell command mysum/1
3>sum:mysum(L).
** exception error: undefined function sum:mysum/1
```

Say what ?  Why am I getting those errors and even though the error messages are just slightly different, I'm thinking maybe their meanings are far apart?

**UPDATE: New code**

```
-module(sum).
-export([sum/1]).

sum(L) -> 
   sum(L, 0).

sum([H|T], Acc) -> 
   sum(T, H + Acc); 

sum([], Acc) ->
   Acc.
```

Then

```
1>L = [1,2,3].
[1,2,3]
2>sum:sum(L).
** exception error: no function clause matching sum:sum([1,2,3],0)
```

Comment: I copied that updated code and works perfectly. `6> L=[1,2,3].
[1,2,3]
7> sum:sum(L).
6
`.

Comment: same here, no exception with the new code

Answer (score 9):

The file should be called `mysum.erl`, the same as the name in the `-module` directive. Anything else is a compiler error in Erlang.

**Make sure that you have compiled it using `c(mysum)` in the shell (and you're in the directory that `mysum.erl` is in.**

Since your module is named `mysum` and the exported function is named `mysum`, thus you should call it with:

```
3> mysum:mysum(L)
```

Also, the variable that you store the results in, `acc`, should be named `Acc` (capital a). Otherwise, it's an atom and you will get a `function_clause` error as soon as you call `mysum(L, 0)` because no clause handles `0` as a second argument (`0` merely compared to the atom `acc`).

Comment: Good catch, but I don't think so.  In my first revision everything was sum (i.e. replace everywhere you see mysum with sum) and yet, I still have the same error.  So I though sum might collide with something so I renamed mysum to sum.  Anyway, I just tried on my console, and your answer wasn't it.

Comment: My first comment no longer applies since you changed your answer.  Good catch about Acc instead of acc though.  I reverted back to my first revision by replacing **mysum** with **sum** everywhere.  But now, when I run **sum:sum(L)**, I'm getting the exception "no function clause matching sum:sum([1, 3, 7], 0)".

Comment: Yes, your new code is correct. It seems that your problem is that you don't recompile the module between tries. Do that and see if it works.

Answer (score 3):

Your new code seems to work. Try recompiling:

```
1> c(sum).
{ok,sum}    
2> sum:sum([1, 2, 3]).
6
```

The `erl` command will load any existing `.beam` files; an explicit compilation is required to reload your code. Check out the [Compiling the code](http://learnyousomeerlang.com/modules#compiling-the-code) section of Learn You Some Erlang for more details.

Comment: I just tried on a different computer and it works just like you said.  I have to go back to the first computer this morning an re-try.

Comment: You called a nonexisting function sum:sum/2 while you meant to call sum:sum/1. The latter is exported, but the former is not.