# Where I am wrong in this module code

Tags: erlang

I have created a module with the below code

```
 -module('calc') .
 -export([sum/2]) . (0)

 sum(L) -> sum(L,0);   (1)
 sum([],N) -> N;   (2)
 sum([H|T], N) -> sum(T, H + N) (3) .
```

and in shell, when I compile it is returning me error like below

```
 calc.erl:5: head mismatch
 calc.erl:2: function sum/2 undefined
 error
```

As per my understanding from the book, 1 clause will receive the list and will pass it to the (3). Then (3) will return the desired result.
But I don't know where I have committed the mistake. Please help me on this.

`And please help me to understand what is /2 in export statement.`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have a syntax error at line (1). The functions sum/1 and sum/2 are different, so your code should look like:

```
sum(L) -> sum(L,0). %% notice the . instead of ;

sum([],N) -> N;
sum([H|T], N) -> sum(T, H + N).
```

The /2 is the **arity** of your function, that is, the number of arguments it takes. So, in your case, the function you want to export is sum/1.

Answer (score 0):

Check this link

[Write a function that calculate the sum of integers in a list in Erlang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7408454/write-a-function-that-calculate-the-sum-of-integers-in-a-list-in-erlang)

/2 in export statement indicates the number of arguments to the function sum.